# Proper flag for personal information

Tags: support, flags

I recently ran across an "answer" with just a statement that they had the same problem, with request for contact, and an email address provided. Nothing more. I'll avoid linking it to avoid the meta effect, plus it'll certainly be removed.

I initially flagged it for moderator intervention, as it's far more than just "not an answer". A minute or two later, I retracted that and went for the more standard "not an answer" flag, because it doesn't necessarily need a moderator, and would likely get addressed quicker.

What is the proper flag to use for something like this?

Comment: Also, see [What should I do if a user posts sensitive information as part of a question or answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132117/what-should-i-do-if-a-user-posts-sensitive-information-as-part-of-a-question-or). In your case, I'd still edit out the PII before flagging to reduce exposure, even if it will eventually be deleted.

Comment: @TemporalWolf not exactly the subject of the question.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use Not an Answer. The folks in [LQP](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts) will quickly devour this in a few hours, while custom flags can take [weeks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfryC.jpg) to be handled. This really is just a plain non-answer.

Never mind that discussing answers in *private* emails goes completely against the Stack Overflow philosophy.

Comment: Can you clarify what LQP is?

Comment: @Wilson the **L**ow **Q**uality **P**osts review queue.

Comment: It's worth noting there are [more than 12k users who can view deleted posts](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/430132/split-users-by-amount-of-reputation-digits), so if it contains personal information it should still be flagged for redaction. In this case, it's less severe, but I'm of the opinion PII should be mitigated **and then** redacted.

Comment: @TemporalWolf: Is that all? Wow. I would have expected that figure to be at least an order of magnitude higher. TIL.

Comment: @TemporalWolf Personal information *deliberately posted* is not so much of an issue. Redactions are usually done for accidentally revealing information.